# How to get the current page no. in flex paper?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

there is no tags on flex paper.
so make tag on flex paper.

Now the question..
How do i get the page number in [flex paper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/).
I want to add some events when page is changed.
And i also want some events on particular some pages. so i need that current page number which is viewing by the user in flex paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From API page: at http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/wiki/API

...
getCurrPage (no args.) : get the currently viewed page 
...

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('Current page:' + getDocViewer().getCurrPage())
```

That should get you want you need. getDocViewer() get the instance of FlexPaper in the page.

getCurrPage is one of it's methods.

See example page here : http://flexpaper.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Example/flash/debug/FlexPaperViewer.html

Be sure your page and Flash object have loaded completely before you call this method.